# Parsing output from scraped webpage using pandas and bs4: way to make output more readable?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wanted to scrape [this](http://yadamp.unisa.it/showItem.aspx?yadampid=18) page.

I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://yadamp.unisa.it/showItem.aspx?yadampid=18")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
print(df[0].to_json(orient='records'))
```

But the output isn't ideal. The output is:

```
[{"0":"ID","1":"18","2":"NAME","3":"Colutellin-A Blast NCBI-PROT","4":null,"5":null},{"0":"LENGTH","1":"7","2":"DISULFIDE  BRIDGE","3":null,"4":"View PDB  \/\/ Small molecules can be embedded in the page  var glmol02 = new GLmol('glmol02');","5":null},{"0":"SEQUENCE","1":"VISIIPV","2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null},{"0":"HELICITY","1":"85.70","2":"INSTAB. INDEX","3":"31.97","4":"FLEXIBILITY","5":"5.43"},{"0":"a HYD. MOM.","1":"16.35","2":"b HYD. MOM.","3":"9.04","4":"c HYD. MOM","5":"1.37"},{"0":"a MEAN HYD.  MOM.","1":"2.34","2":"b MEAN HYD.  MOM.","3":"1.29","4":"c MEAN HYD.  MOM.","5":"0.20"},{"0":"CHARGE pH5","1":"0.00","2":"CHARGE pH7","3":"0.00","4":"CHARGE pH9","5":"-0.17"},{"0":"\u0394 CHARGE pH5-pH9","1":"0.17","2":"ISOELECTRIC POINT","3":"5.49","4":"BOMAN INDEX","5":"-2.78"},{"0":"\u0394G","1":"-368","2":"CPP","3":"-027","4":"MLP","5":"-006"},{"0":"MOLECULAR VOLUME","1":null,"2":"POLARITY","3":null,"4":null,"5":null},{"0":"MIC E. coli","1":null,"2":"MIC P. aeruginosa","3":null,"4":"MIC S. typhimurium","5":null},{"0":"MIC S. aureus","1":null,"2":"MIC M. luteus","3":null,"4":"MIC B. subtilis","5":null},{"0":"MIC C. albicans","1":null,"2":"OTHER","3":"S.sclerotiorum = 30.86; B.cinerea = 10.29","4":null,"5":null},{"0":"MIC OTHER  gram+","1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null},{"0":"MIC OTHERgram-","1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null},{"0":"PHYLUM","1":"Ascomycota","2":"CLASS","3":"Sordariomycetes","4":"ORDER","5":"Glomerellales"},{"0":"FAMILY","1":"Glomerellaceae","2":"GENUS","3":"Colletotrichum","4":"SPECIES","5":"Colletotrichum dematium"},{"0":"DATE","1":"2008","2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null},{"0":"TITLE PAPER","1":"Colutellin A, an immunosuppressive peptide from Colletotrichum dematium","2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null}]
```

You can see it's difficult for me to make sense of this list, because I have to loop through a list of multiple dictionaries, and then join pairs of keys together. I was hoping the output would be more like:

```
ID 18
Name Colutellin-A
Helicity 85.7
```

etc....just something more readable. Can anyone pinpoint a section of the code that I should change to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: Using pandas for this is overkill. Loop through each row in the table and find the <td> elements and extract the ones you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas `read_html()` to get the table and then navigate the table using pandas `DataFrame()`, see the code below!

```
url = 'http://yadamp.unisa.it/showItem.aspx?yadampid=18'
table = pd.read_html(url, attrs={
    'class': 'table table-responsive'}, header=0)
print(pd.DataFrame(table[0]))
```